# Bot Listening to every message in a teams channel

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

### Listening to every message sent even without @mention to bot in a teams channel

We are building a support bot which runs on Microsoft Teams Only.
Actually our bot only receives messages which contain a mention to it.
But the ideal scenario will be to listen to every message sent into the specific channel.
I went arround Microsoft Docs, and found out it was [not actually possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-channel#-mentions) to implement this later scenario
I also looked at [Bot-Builder Microsoft Teams SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams), but this right now as I'm writing this is available only for SDK v3 which should be deprecated by now.
Is there a way to by-pass the constraint of not being able to listen to every message in a Teams channel with V4 SDK ?

Comment: Bots in channels [receive messages only when they are explicitly @mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/troubleshoot/faq#how-can-my-bot-access-or-listen-to-all-messages-in-a-channel). There is no way to grant your bot access to conversations in which they are not mentioned.

Comment: This should be submitted as a feature request (you're certainly not the only one who wants this capability).

Comment: Yeah @EricHansen I did that already on Github.

Comment: @JohnCode Could you link the github issue where you did this?

Comment: @JohnCode were you able to find a solution for this?